# How to access an un-keyed element of an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that comes from a CMS, which means I can't change how it comes to me. The array is named $master_menu; this is the `print_r`:

```
Array
(
    [A] => Array
        (
            [ ] => Appetizer
            [PROD] => Array
                (
                    [AC] => Order Anchovies
                    [AL] => Side Alfredo Sauce
                    [AO] => Add On
                    )
        )
)
```

I have a variable called `$class` that contains 'A'. I know I can get at the entire A sub-array like this:

```
$master_menu[$class]
```

and I could get at the PROD sub-array like this:

```
$master_menu[$class]['PROD']
```

But how can I just get the value in the sub-array without a key (value is Appetizer in this sample)? I've tried `$master_menu[$class][0]`, but obviously that doesn't work because there isn't a sub-array with a zero index.

Comment: To get better debug output use `var_dump($var)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empty index is a space `$master_menu["A"][" "]`. Try using `var_dump` instead of `print_r`, it has more details.

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as an element without a key. Maybe the key is `" "` ? I think that'd be consistent with your `print_r` output.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like print_r gave you a space as an index. Try:

```
$master_menu[$class][" "]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_values` and parse that out.

*Edit*: It looks like you might be able to access the empty key ' '... perhaps `$master_menu[$class][' ']`.. just a thought as I'm not sure the exact output.